# CTX index in oracle is quite slow?

Tags: oracle

I am using CTX index in oracle column .

I have two table

```
xyz have 6 million record.
abc has 100k record
```

What i want to achieve is this.

**Scenario** - I have to union them and then i need the data in order by of date . And then i need pagination record on them.

```
  select page_loc, blurb_id, article_id, hit_date,val_rank  from (
           SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(regexp_replace(page_loc, '^.*mercer\.com'),'\?.*$') AS  page_loc,
           blurb_id, article_id, hit_date,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY hit_date DESC) AS val_rank
           from (
             SELECT  page_loc, blurb_id, article_id, hit_date
             FROM abc u INNER JOIN person p ON u.person_id=p.person_id
             WHERE (CONTAINS(u.page_loc,v_pattern) > 0 )
               UNION ALL
             SELECT e page_loc, blurb_id, article_id, hit_date
             FROM xyz u INNER JOIN person p ON u.person_id=p.person_id
             WHERE  ( CONTAINS(u.page_loc,v_pattern) > 0)
          ) p
            left join
          company c on c.company_id = p.company_id
          ) a
          where val_rank between (v_page_no -1) * 10  and v_page_no * 10
```

v_pattern --> searching text
v_page_no --> page count

It take long time when i have record for some v_pattern more e.g 100k,

**for example** a word have 2 million record. it take more than 20 min.

Any idea what can i do . or it is not possible with oracle.

**NOTE :-  when i analysis it i found order by and pagination making it slow . How can i overcome that**

Comment: `or it is not possible with oracle.` Every time I hear/read I just laugh. Oracle/MS SQL Server/any enterprise DB are very capable. So instead of making such statement I would recommend to 1) gather statistics 2) make sure you have index on `hit_date`  3) move REGEXP_REPLACE to most outer query. And finally without your schema it is really hard to help more.

Comment: I have done index on all join columns and hist_date too. let me replace the regexp then will come up with some analytics .